# Is this the right way of following this flowchart?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if my code snippet below exactly follows my flowchart.

```
//necessary variables for my code
var balance = -1;  this one check the balance of the bank account
var checkBalance = true; //asking if i want to checkBalance
var isActive = true;     //if my bank account is active or not


//  this is the code that checks the variables 

if(checkBalance){ // if true then keep going to check the others


    if(isActive && balance > 0){
        console.log("Your balance is $" + balance.toFixed(2) + ".");
    }
    else if(!isActive){
        console.log("Your account is no longer Active.");
    }
    else if(balance === 0){
        console.log("Your account is empty.");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Your balance is negative. please contact the                 bank.");
    }
}else{ // if check balance = false
    console.log("Thank you. Have a nice day!")
}
```

Comment: what flowchart?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dBqFQ2I

Comment: Looks like a spot on representation of that flowchart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var balance =  -1;
var checkBalance = true;
var isActive = true;

if (checkBalance === true && isActive === false) {console.log("Your account is no longer active.");}
else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance > 0) {console.log("Your balance is $ " + balance.toFixed(2) +".");}
else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance === 0) {console.log("Your account is empty.");}
else if (checkBalance === true && isActive === true && balance < 0) {console.log("Your balance is negative. Please contact the bank.");}
else {console.log("Thank you have a nice day!");}
```

Comment: Huh this is completely right, Thanks for helping

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSalah please accept my answer thanks